# How To Deal With Hinges In Statically Indeterminate Structures?

Tags: civil-engineering

In a statically indeterminate structure, solving the beam using slope deflection method how to cater for the beams with hinges? How would i calculate the FEMS for such beam? Do i have to consider hinge as a Far End Pinned or else? Also If The load is applied directly on the hinge, then how to cater for such a scenario. I have an upcoming Exam and if someone can clear that doubt to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with a point force acting right on the hinge of a beam?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/how-to-deal-with-a-point-force-acting-right-on-the-hinge-of-a-beam)

Comment: Specify moment at hinge as zero, and do the calculation. That should do the trick.